# Proving an integral inequality where $x$ is complex.

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-method

Is it possible to prove the below inequality:
$$
\left\lvert{\int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon e^{-xt^2}\left(e^{-xR(t)}-1\right)\mathrm{d}{t}}\right\rvert
 \leq C\left\lvert x\int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon e^{-xt^2}\lvert{t}\rvert^3\mathrm{d}{t}\right\rvert \qquad\text{where } x\in \mathbb{C}, \lvert x\rvert \gg 0, \Re(x)\geq 0
$$
Here, $R(t)$ is $O(t^3)$ and we have the freedom to pick any $\varepsilon >0$.

Thanks in advance!

My idea: The inequality is trivial if $x$ is real. So for the complex case, I want $\varepsilon$ to be small so that $e^{-xt^2}$ is "almost" real. I am looking for a way to write this out rigorously.

Comment: Write out the Taylor series for $e^{-x R(t)}$ and see what happens. What have you tried, where did you encounter this, and what's giving you trouble? Please [edit] to improve your question.

Comment: Perhaps.  What work have you done to answer this question?  Please add your work, and/or any thoughts on how to proceed, directly in your answer box by editing your post.

Comment: Sorry about that. I accidentally posted the question before I was done writing it!